# How should I make a Image Editor using python, without using any library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, bitmap, python-imaging-library

I don't want to use any library. And learn popular image processing algorithms and implement it. Purely using Python.

It's my project in college. Not anything fancy, just want to implement simple image processing algorithms on Bitmap.

Comment: Let's be honest. If you're trying to reinvent the wheel, it'll take you 5 (maybe 10) years to make anything as good as what's currently available, and by that time there's bound to be something better.

Comment: He don't want to invent the wheel, just make a project that let him to understand the foundations of image editing, I would start with what is image for computer, also it would be better if you expend your question with another detailed about what exactly are you tending to do

Comment: why don't you want to use a library? It is practically impossible to do what you ask

Comment: Well... you will at some point use some libraries. Your images will come in formats such as jpeg, and you need to use a library to decode them, otherwise forget about learning basic image processing and do this first. If you are willing to make concessions, and use something like scipy/numpy/etc to read/write images, then you can start implementing simple stuff like edge detectors (old school canny), then move on to implement stuff like feature matching and so on.

Comment: Are you ok with built in libraries?

Comment: try installing pip. It will allow you to easily download libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I'll give you a start without libraries.

```
filer=open('turkey.png','rb')
print(filer.read())
filer.close()
```

Then you have to figure out a way to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Simple answer. Python on its own does not have any libraries pre-installed or pre-imported for manipulating pictures. Why wouldn't you use libraries? If you are building a big project or even a smaller one, I think you will need to `import` a library. Python is very dependent on libraries! Maybe in the future if python has a pre-installed & pre-imported library for picture editing! :)